# PHP Constructors: Will an "inherited" constructor use Inherited or Parent class overriden methods?

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor

Let's say I have a class

```
class Item {

public function __construct($id) {
     if(!empty($id)) {
         $this->doSomethingWithID($id);
     }
}

public function dummyMethod() {
    //does Something.
}

protected function doSomethingWithID($id) {
    //Does something with the ID
}

}
```

If I have an inherited class like this:

```
class Product extends Item {

 public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
 }

 protected function doSomethingWithID($id) {
      //OVERRIDES THE PARENT FUNCTION
 }

}
```

Will the Product class use the overridden Method? or will it use the Parent method?

Comment: You could try it out and see

Comment: Had no way, because I was working on someone's else code and didn't find a safe way to test, just wanted to make sure it works the way I think so I can keep on analysing it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more specific something is, the higher priority it gets in code.

Children with methods of the same name as their parents take priority.  You CAN call a parents methods by saying `super.method()` though.

Comment: That's right. If the children's constructor uses a method that is overridden in its class it won't use the parent's method.

Comment: Sorry, did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: No, I'm giving you the reason, you're right when you say Children's methods take the priority.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a new construct method in the inherited class so it will use that, but as the inherited class calls the parent class construct method it will use that.